# How to store long text in Android?

Tags: android, string, localization, textview

I usually used short messages in `strings.xml` for `TextView`s and other widgets. Where can I store long texts? What if I need to store a big user guide and localize it then?

```
<string name="instruction_will_be_soon">Lorem Ipsum ist ein einfacher Demo-Text für die Print- und Schriftindustrie. Lorem Ipsum ist in der Industrie bereits der Standard Demo-Text seit 1500, als ein unbekannter Schriftsteller eine Hand voll Wörter nahm und diese durcheinander warf um ein Musterbuch zu erstellen. Es hat nicht nur 5 Jahrhunderte überlebt, sondern auch in Spruch in die elektronische Schriftbearbeitung geschafft (bemerke, nahezu unverändert). Bekannt wurde es 1960, mit dem erscheinen von "Letraset", welches Passagen von Lorem Ipsum enhielt, so wie Desktop Software wie "Aldus PageMaker" - ebenfalls mit Lorem Ipsum. Glauben oder nicht glauben, Lorem Ipsum ist nicht nur ein zufälliger Text. Er hat Wurzeln aus der Lateinischen Literatur von 45 v. Chr, was ihn über 2000 Jahre alt macht. Richar McClintock, ein Lateinprofessor des Hampden-Sydney College in Virgnia untersuche einige undeutliche Worte, "consectetur", einer Lorem Ipsum Passage und fand eine unwiederlegbare Quelle. Lorem Ipsum komm aus der Sektion 1.10.32 und 1.10.33 des "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (Die Extreme von Gut und Böse) von Cicero, geschrieben 45 v. Chr. Dieses Buch ist Abhandlung der Ethiktheorien, sehr bekannt wärend der Renaissance. Die erste Zeile des Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...", kommt aus einer Zeile der Sektion 1.10.32.</string>
```

Comment: I wasn't aware there was a limit to the length of the strings.xml...

Comment: If you need to store really large texts - use this http://stackoverflow.com/a/40456754/7045114

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think the strings.xml has a limit, so it would be best to store your longest strings in there.  That's really the only Android-designated place to store strings, so if you want to really use a different storage mechanism, you'll have to load the string from a file or database.

Comment: Thank you. I think that the most convenient way to store texts is to store them in XMLs.